# How to get arguments with flags in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I know that I can easily get positioned parameters like this in bash:

`$0` or `$1`

I want to be able to use flag options like this to specify for what each parameter is used:

```
mysql -u user -h host
```

What is the best way to get `-u param` value and `-h param` value by flag instead of by position?

Comment: It might be a good idea to ask/check over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: google for "bash getopts" -- lots of tutorials.

Comment: @glenn-jackman: I will definately google it now that I know the name. The thing about google is - to ask a question - you should already know 50% of the answer.

Comment: Have a look at [BashFAQ#035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

Answer (score 392, accepted):

This is the idiom I usually use:

```
while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    -h|--help)
      echo "$package - attempt to capture frames"
      echo " "
      echo "$package [options] application [arguments]"
      echo " "
      echo "options:"
      echo "-h, --help                show brief help"
      echo "-a, --action=ACTION       specify an action to use"
      echo "-o, --output-dir=DIR      specify a directory to store output in"
      exit 0
      ;;
    -a)
      shift
      if test $# -gt 0; then
        export PROCESS=$1
      else
        echo "no process specified"
        exit 1
      fi
      shift
      ;;
    --action*)
      export PROCESS=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
      shift
      ;;
    -o)
      shift
      if test $# -gt 0; then
        export OUTPUT=$1
      else
        echo "no output dir specified"
        exit 1
      fi
      shift
      ;;
    --output-dir*)
      export OUTPUT=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'`
      shift
      ;;
    *)
      break
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Key points are:

- `$#` is the number of arguments
- while loop looks at all the arguments supplied, matching on their values inside a case statement
- shift takes the first one away. You can shift multiple times inside of a case statement to take multiple values.

Comment: What does the `--action*` and `--output-dir*` cases do?

Comment: They just save the values they get into the environment.

Comment: @Lucio Super old comment, but adding it in case someone else ever visits this page. The * (wildcard) is for the case where someone types `--action=[ACTION]` as well as the case where someone types `--action [ACTION]`

Comment: Why for `*)` do you break there, shouldn't you exit or ignore the bad option? In other words `-bad -o dir` the `-o dir` part is never processed.

Comment: @newguy good question. I think I was trying to let them fall through to something else

Comment: @jimmy you added a bug - `$1` is `--action=blah` so you are the whole thing before sed could find the blah.

Comment: maybe I'm stupid, but this is the only one that worked for me

Comment: You can replace `export PROCESS='echo $1 | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//g'` with `export PROCESS="${1/*"="/}"`

Comment: I can never quite remember what's a bashism and what's not, so I tend to keep avoid constructs like that

Comment: @cooper Super old comment, but how the * would catch a `space` in `$1`?

Comment: It doesn't actually do that, you could conditionally shift another argument in that case though

Comment: Hi, all can anyone share an example using this? I don't understand how to pass a command into this loop????

Comment: It's popping them from $@, $# is the the size of $@, so `./my_script blah blah blah` is sufficient here

Comment: How to pass zero parameters?

Comment: You can use parameter expansion instead of `sed` and example would be `${1#[^=]*[ =]}`

Answer (score 676):

This example uses Bash's built-in [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) command and is from the [Google Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=Case_statement#Case_statement):

```
a_flag=''
b_flag=''
files=''
verbose='false'

print_usage() {
  printf "Usage: ..."
}

while getopts 'abf:v' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    a) a_flag='true' ;;
    b) b_flag='true' ;;
    f) files="${OPTARG}" ;;
    v) verbose='true' ;;
    *) print_usage
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
```

*Note: If a character is followed by a colon (e.g. `f:`), that option is expected to have an argument.*

Example usage: `./script -v -a -b -f filename`

Using getopts has several advantages over the accepted answer:

- the while condition is a lot more readable and shows what the accepted options are
- cleaner code; no counting the number of parameters and shifting
- you can join options (e.g. `-a -b -c` → `-abc`)

However, a big disadvantage is that it doesn't support long options, only single-character options.

Comment: For posterity: the colon after in 'abf:v' denotes that -f takes an additional argument (the filename in this case).

Comment: I had to change the error line to this: `?) printf '\nUsage: %s: [-a] aflag [-b] bflag\n' $0; exit 2 ;;`

Comment: Could you add a note about the colons?  In that after each letter, no colon means no arg, one colon means an arg, and two colons means optional arg?

Comment: What's the `error` command in the `*)` fallback? Couldn't find any such command on Ubuntu.

Comment: @nachtigall that would be a function named `error` declared before its usage. It could, for example, print the error message passed to it and then exit with a non-zero status. Sorry for the confusion, I'll change the example to be more clear.

Comment: @WillBarnwell one should note that it was added 3 years after the question was asked, whereas the top answer was added on the same day.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas forgot to mention, the Aug 9 update should fix the EOF error

Comment: Is it possible to use this method for `--help`?

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh it won't work for `--help` because it's a long option. Use `-h` instead.

Comment: i read something about optional arg is there a way to run a command depending on whether args are supplied or not? *) doesn't seem to help

Comment: @Fuseteam after processing the arguments, check if the option was provided. https://pastebin.com/zrLGS48x

Comment: @Dennis that is actually what i ended up doing, setting flags for the required options and checking of all the required flags are true, if not print usage, thanks ^_^

Comment: why does this idiom set variables to 'true' insetad of true ?

Comment: @WillBarnwell a possible reason for this is that `getopts` is incompatible between Unix and Linux. Furthermore, it limits in complex arguments, can't compatibly handle long arguments, and if you think about it, it just removes a couple of `shift` 's in the code. It does have a couple of benefits, but they are minor.

Comment: One can use `$OPTIND` to figure out how many options/flags were passed.

Comment: I actually found this much nicer to work with positional arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311441/consume-command-args-in-a-case-statement-in-bash. But I didn't need arguments on my options.

Answer (score 53):

getopt is your friend.. a simple example:

```
function f () {
TEMP=`getopt --long -o "u:h:" "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -u )
            user=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        -h )
            host=$2
            shift 2
        ;;
        *)
            break
        ;;
    esac 
done;

echo "user = $user, host = $host"
}

f -u myself -h some_host
```

There should be various examples in your /usr/bin directory.

Comment: A more extensive example can be found in the directory `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples`, at the very least on Ubuntu machines.

Comment: @Shizzmo Can you explain the syntax of `set --` ? I have seen this idiom a few times now. Would be grateful. Thanks alot.

Comment: @vonspotz https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308263/192430

Answer (score 34):

I propose a simple TLDR:; example for the un-initiated.

**Create a bash script called greeter.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "n:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    n) Name=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

echo "Hello $Name!"
```

You can then pass an optional parameter `-n` when executing the script.

**Execute the script as such:**

```
$ bash greeter.sh -n 'Bob'
```

**Output**

```
$ Hello Bob!
```

**Notes**

If you'd like to use multiple parameters:

1. extend `while getops "n:" arg: do` with more paramaters such as
   `while getops "n:o:p:" arg: do`
2. extend the case switch with extra variable assignments. Such as `o) Option=$OPTARG` and `p) Parameter=$OPTARG`

To make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x greeter.sh
```

Answer (score 19):

I think this would serve as a simpler example of what you want to achieve. There is no need to use external tools. Bash built in tools can do the job for you.

```
function DOSOMETHING {

   while test $# -gt 0; do
           case "$1" in
                -first)
                    shift
                    first_argument=$1
                    shift
                    ;;
                -last)
                    shift
                    last_argument=$1
                    shift
                    ;;
                *)
                   echo "$1 is not a recognized flag!"
                   return 1;
                   ;;
          esac
  done  

  echo "First argument : $first_argument";
  echo "Last argument : $last_argument";
 }
```

This will allow you to use flags so no matter which order you are passing the parameters you will get the proper behavior.

Example :

```
 DOSOMETHING -last "Adios" -first "Hola"
```

Output :

```
 First argument : Hola
 Last argument : Adios
```

You can add this function to your profile or put it inside of a script.

Thanks!

Edit : 
Save this as a a file and then execute it as `yourfile.sh -last "Adios" -first "Hola"`

```
#!/bin/bash
while test $# -gt 0; do
           case "$1" in
                -first)
                    shift
                    first_argument=$1
                    shift
                    ;;
                -last)
                    shift
                    last_argument=$1
                    shift
                    ;;
                *)
                   echo "$1 is not a recognized flag!"
                   return 1;
                   ;;
          esac
  done  

  echo "First argument : $first_argument";
  echo "Last argument : $last_argument";
```

Comment: I uses above code & when run it is not printing anything.
`./hello.sh DOSOMETHING -last "Adios" -first "Hola"`

Comment: @dinu0101 This is a function. Not a  script. You should use it as DOSOMETHING -last "Adios" -first "Hola"

Comment: Thanks @Matias. Understood. how to run inside script.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Matias

Comment: Using `return 1;` with the last example outputs `can only 'return' from a function or sourced script` on macOS. Switching to `exit 1;` works as expected though.

Comment: Why doesn't it work for me when I try to invoke the function by entering `DOSOMETHING` at the end of the script?

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative would be to use something like the below example which would allow you to use long **--image** or short **-i** tags and also allow compiled **-i="example.jpg"** or separate **-i example.jpg** methods of passing in arguments.

```
# declaring a couple of associative arrays
declare -A arguments=();  
declare -A variables=();

# declaring an index integer
declare -i index=1;

# any variables you want to use here
# on the left left side is argument label or key (entered at the command line along with it's value) 
# on the right side is the variable name the value of these arguments should be mapped to.
# (the examples above show how these are being passed into this script)
variables["-gu"]="git_user";  
variables["--git-user"]="git_user";  
variables["-gb"]="git_branch";  
variables["--git-branch"]="git_branch";  
variables["-dbr"]="db_fqdn";  
variables["--db-redirect"]="db_fqdn";  
variables["-e"]="environment";  
variables["--environment"]="environment";

# $@ here represents all arguments passed in
for i in "$@"  
do  
  arguments[$index]=$i;
  prev_index="$(expr $index - 1)";

  # this if block does something akin to "where $i contains ="
  # "%=*" here strips out everything from the = to the end of the argument leaving only the label
  if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
    then argument_label=${i%=*} 
    else argument_label=${arguments[$prev_index]}
  fi

  # this if block only evaluates to true if the argument label exists in the variables array
  if [[ -n ${variables[$argument_label]} ]]
    then
        # dynamically creating variables names using declare
        # "#$argument_label=" here strips out the label leaving only the value
        if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
            then declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${i#$argument_label=} 
            else declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${arguments[$index]}
        fi
  fi

  index=index+1;
done;

# then you could simply use the variables like so:
echo "$git_user";
```

Answer (score 6):

I like Robert McMahan's answer the best here as it seems the easiest to make into sharable include files for any of your scripts to use.  But it seems to have a flaw with the line `if [[ -n ${variables[$argument_label]} ]]` throwing the message, "variables: bad array subscript".  I don't have the rep to comment, and I doubt this is the proper 'fix,' but wrapping that `if` in `if [[ -n $argument_label ]] ; then` cleans it up.

Here's the code I ended up with, if you know a better way please add a comment to Robert's answer.

Include File "flags-declares.sh"

```
# declaring a couple of associative arrays
declare -A arguments=();
declare -A variables=();

# declaring an index integer
declare -i index=1;
```

Include File "flags-arguments.sh"

```
# $@ here represents all arguments passed in
for i in "$@"
do
  arguments[$index]=$i;
  prev_index="$(expr $index - 1)";

  # this if block does something akin to "where $i contains ="
  # "%=*" here strips out everything from the = to the end of the argument leaving only the label
  if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
    then argument_label=${i%=*}
    else argument_label=${arguments[$prev_index]}
  fi

  if [[ -n $argument_label ]] ; then
    # this if block only evaluates to true if the argument label exists in the variables array
    if [[ -n ${variables[$argument_label]} ]] ; then
      # dynamically creating variables names using declare
      # "#$argument_label=" here strips out the label leaving only the value
      if [[ $i == *"="* ]]
        then declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${i#$argument_label=} 
        else declare ${variables[$argument_label]}=${arguments[$index]}
      fi
    fi
  fi

  index=index+1;
done;
```

Your "script.sh"

```
. bin/includes/flags-declares.sh

# any variables you want to use here
# on the left left side is argument label or key (entered at the command line along with it's value) 
# on the right side is the variable name the value of these arguments should be mapped to.
# (the examples above show how these are being passed into this script)
variables["-gu"]="git_user";
variables["--git-user"]="git_user";
variables["-gb"]="git_branch";
variables["--git-branch"]="git_branch";
variables["-dbr"]="db_fqdn";
variables["--db-redirect"]="db_fqdn";
variables["-e"]="environment";
variables["--environment"]="environment";

. bin/includes/flags-arguments.sh

# then you could simply use the variables like so:
echo "$git_user";
echo "$git_branch";
echo "$db_fqdn";
echo "$environment";
```

Comment: the bad array thing happens if you don't use  an "=" to declare the argument. so -u=git_user works, but -u git_user throws the warning (but still works). I think I'll keep the original just to remind me to always use = in arguments, seems tidyer

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

if getopts "n:" arg; then
  echo "Welcome $OPTARG"
fi
```

Save it as sample.sh
and try running

```
sh sample.sh -n John
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with Python argparse, and don't mind calling python to parse bash arguments, there is a piece of code I found really helpful and super easy to use called argparse-bash
https://github.com/nhoffman/argparse-bash

Example take from their example.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $(dirname $0)/argparse.bash || exit 1
argparse "$@" <<EOF || exit 1
parser.add_argument('infile')
parser.add_argument('outfile')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--the-answer', default=42, type=int,
                    help='Pick a number [default %(default)s]')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--do-the-thing', action='store_true',
                    default=False, help='store a boolean [default %(default)s]')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--multiple', nargs='+',
                    help='multiple values allowed')
EOF

echo required infile: "$INFILE"
echo required outfile: "$OUTFILE"
echo the answer: "$THE_ANSWER"
echo -n do the thing?
if [[ $DO_THE_THING ]]; then
    echo " yes, do it"
else
    echo " no, do not do it"
fi
echo -n "arg with multiple values: "
for a in "${MULTIPLE[@]}"; do
    echo -n "[$a] "
done
echo
```

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble using getopts with multiple flags, so I wrote this code.  It uses a modal variable to detect flags, and to use those flags to assign arguments to variables.

Note that, if a flag shouldn't have an argument, something other than setting CURRENTFLAG can be done.

```
    for MYFIELD in "$@"; do

        CHECKFIRST=`echo $MYFIELD | cut -c1`

        if [ "$CHECKFIRST" == "-" ]; then
            mode="flag"
        else
            mode="arg"
        fi

        if [ "$mode" == "flag" ]; then
            case $MYFIELD in
                -a)
                    CURRENTFLAG="VARIABLE_A"
                    ;;
                -b)
                    CURRENTFLAG="VARIABLE_B"
                    ;;
                -c)
                    CURRENTFLAG="VARIABLE_C"
                    ;;
            esac
        elif [ "$mode" == "arg" ]; then
            case $CURRENTFLAG in
                VARIABLE_A)
                    VARIABLE_A="$MYFIELD"
                    ;;
                VARIABLE_B)
                    VARIABLE_B="$MYFIELD"
                    ;;
                VARIABLE_C)
                    VARIABLE_C="$MYFIELD"
                    ;;
            esac
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

So here it is my solution. I wanted to be able to handle boolean flags without hyphen, with one hyphen, and with two hyphen as well as parameter/value assignment with one and two hyphens.

```sh
# Handle multiple types of arguments and prints some variables
#
# Boolean flags
# 1) No hyphen
#    create   Assigns `true` to the variable `CREATE`.
#             Default is `CREATE_DEFAULT`.
#    delete   Assigns true to the variable `DELETE`.
#             Default is `DELETE_DEFAULT`.
# 2) One hyphen
#      a      Assigns `true` to a. Default is `false`.
#      b      Assigns `true` to b. Default is `false`.
# 3) Two hyphens
#    cats     Assigns `true` to `cats`. By default is not set.
#    dogs     Assigns `true` to `cats`. By default is not set.
#
# Parameter - Value
# 1) One hyphen
#      c      Assign any value you want
#      d      Assign any value you want
#
# 2) Two hyphens
#   ... Anything really, whatever two-hyphen argument is given that is not
#       defined as flag, will be defined with the next argument after it.
#
# Example:
# ./parser_example.sh delete -a -c VA_1 --cats --dir /path/to/dir
parser() {
    # Define arguments with one hyphen that are boolean flags
    HYPHEN_FLAGS="a b"
    # Define arguments with two hyphens that are boolean flags
    DHYPHEN_FLAGS="cats dogs"

    # Iterate over all the arguments
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        # Handle the arguments with no hyphen
        if [[ $1 != "-"* ]]; then
            echo "Argument with no hyphen!"
            echo $1
            # Assign true to argument $1
            declare $1=true
            # Shift arguments by one to the left
            shift
        # Handle the arguments with one hyphen
        elif [[ $1 == "-"[A-Za-z0-9]* ]]; then
            # Handle the flags
            if [[ $HYPHEN_FLAGS == *"${1/-/}"* ]]; then
                echo "Argument with one hyphen flag!"
                echo $1
                # Remove the hyphen from $1
                local param="${1/-/}"
                # Assign true to $param
                declare $param=true
                # Shift by one
                shift
            # Handle the parameter-value cases
            else
                echo "Argument with one hyphen value!"
                echo $1 $2
                # Remove the hyphen from $1
                local param="${1/-/}"
                # Assign argument $2 to $param
                declare $param="$2"
                # Shift by two
                shift 2
            fi
        # Handle the arguments with two hyphens
        elif [[ $1 == "--"[A-Za-z0-9]* ]]; then
            # NOTE: For double hyphen I am using `declare -g $param`.
            #   This is the case because I am assuming that's going to be
            #   the final name of the variable
            echo "Argument with two hypens!"
            # Handle the flags
            if [[ $DHYPHEN_FLAGS == *"${1/--/}"* ]]; then
                echo $1 true
                # Remove the hyphens from $1
                local param="${1/--/}"
                # Assign argument $2 to $param
                declare -g $param=true
                # Shift by two
                shift
            # Handle the parameter-value cases
            else
                echo $1 $2
                # Remove the hyphens from $1
                local param="${1/--/}"
                # Assign argument $2 to $param
                declare -g $param="$2"
                # Shift by two
                shift 2
            fi
        fi

    done
    # Default value for arguments with no hypheb
    CREATE=${create:-'CREATE_DEFAULT'}
    DELETE=${delete:-'DELETE_DEFAULT'}
    # Default value for arguments with one hypen flag
    VAR1=${a:-false}
    VAR2=${b:-false}
    # Default value for arguments with value
    # NOTE1: This is just for illustration in one line. We can well create
    #   another function to handle this. Here I am handling the cases where
    #   we have a full named argument and a contraction of it.
    #   For example `--arg1` can be also set with `-c`.
    # NOTE2: What we are doing here is to check if $arg is defined. If not,
    #   check if $c was defined. If not, assign the default value "VD_"
    VAR3=$(if [[ $arg1 ]]; then echo $arg1; else echo ${c:-"VD_1"}; fi)
    VAR4=$(if [[ $arg2 ]]; then echo $arg2; else echo ${d:-"VD_2"}; fi)
}


# Pass all the arguments given to the script to the parser function
parser "$@"


echo $CREATE $DELETE $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3 $VAR4 $cats $dir
```

## Some references

- The main procedure was found [here](https://brianchildress.co/named-parameters-in-bash/).
- More about passing all the arguments to a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816747/5969548).
- More info regarding default values [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/404005).
- More info about `declare` do `$ bash -c "help declare"`.
- More info about `shift` do `$ bash -c "help shift"`.