# Consume command args in a case statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, case

I have a case statement that takes part of my command and I want it to go through all of the args until they've all been consumed.

```
while [ ! -z ${@:2} ] ; do
    case "${@:2}" in
        -d|--delete*)
            YES_DELETE=1
            shift
            ;;        
        -nd|--nodelete*)
            NO_DELETE=1
            shift
            ;;
        -y|--yes*)
            SKIP_PROMPT=1
            shift
            ;;
        -*|*)
            echo "Bad command, try again."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

My command `$@` is `$ mpip stt=12 -nd -y` which makes `${@:2}="-nd -y"`.
If it were to work like I wanted it too, it would exit the while loop after iterating twice and `NO_DELETE=1 SKIP_PROMPT=1` would be true. When I run it, everything is still uninitialized and it turns into an infinite loop and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: btw, `"${@:2}"` is `( -nd -y )`, not `"-nd -y"`, in your example -- it's an array, not a string. Data types are important. (And expanding a multi-element array into a test command... well, short form is that it generally doesn't work well; don't do that).

Comment: also, use lower-case names for your own variables. See fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html (keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace).

Comment: BTW, `"${@:2}"` is quite emphatically not the same thing as `"$2"`, which is what you appear to actually want -- at least as the argument to `case`, where passing an array consisting of `$2` **and all subsequent arguments** on each iteration through the loop makes no sense.

Comment: ...if you *did* want `"-nd -y"` for the test, by the way, that would be `"${*:2}"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You were right, i was looking `$2` after all, thanks! I suppose I was passing all the args to `case` at once instead of doing each arg individually? And the variable naming is a convention I had to follow which is why it's like that.

Comment: Understood -- but if you have a site-local convention contrary to POSIX, you might point that contradiction out to the folks behind it. (Lots of folks who are self-taught see the upper-case variable names used by the shell and system and assume that that's how all variable names are supposed to be, rather than that being the specific namespace reserved for shell and system-impacting variables).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of trying to work around your positional arguments, pop them out of the way. This makes your logic much simpler, and your command-line interface more user-friendly (since it can have positional arguments **following** options in that case, which is actually the POSIX-standard-formula for command-line parsing -- indeed, POSIX tools aren't required to allow options to follow positional arguments at all, though GNU tools conventionally do so as an extension).

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- IMPORTANT: Not /bin/sh

args=( ) # positional arguments

# completely empty the argv, shifting positional options into "${args[@]}" and processing
# option flags.
while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    -d)   yes_delete=1 ;;
    -nd)  no_delete=1 ;;
    -y)   skip_prompt=1 ;;
    -*)   echo "Bad option" >&2; exit 1 ;;
    --)   shift; args+=( "$@" ); set -- ;;
    *)    args+=( "$1" ) ;;
  esac
  shift
done

# with options popped off, make our positional arguments the whole argument list
set -- "${args[@]}"

# examples of positional argument validation
(( "$#" )) || { echo "Error: At least one argument is required" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ $1 != *=* ]] || { echo "Error: First argument must contain an = sign" >&2; exit 1; }
```

Comment: I had to change to `set -- "${args[@]:-""}"` to account for the case where no positional args are supplied, lest I get a "args[@]: unbound variable" error.

Comment: @levigroker `args=( ); set -- "${args[@]}"` doesn't cause any error with default shell settings. If you enabled `set -u`... well, it's not considered a universal bad idea [the way `set -e` is](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105), but it definitely [has its downsides](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112); I recommend static checking with http://shellcheck.net/ instead.

Comment: @levigroker, ...particularly, I'd argue that `set -- "${args[@]:-""}"` is itself a bad idea because it sets `$#` to `1` when it should be `0`, inserting a `""` argument when there should be no arguments at all.

Comment: @levigroker, ...what I'd use instead is `set -- ${args+"${args[@]}"}`

Comment: Thanks. I do run with `set -u` so that's likely the culprit. I like your suggestion about using `set -- ${args+"${args[@]}"}`. Cheers.