# bash script does not assign flags to variable

Tags: linux, bash, getopt

I have a bash file where I am passing arguments like

```
bash foo.sh update -f /var/ -v true
```

so [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128172/7342807) my script should look like

```
if [[ "$1" == "update" ]]; then
    updater 
fi

function updater(){
    verbose='false'
    fflag=''
    error=''

while getopts 'f:v' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in 
    f) fflag="${OPTARG}";;
    v) verbose='false';;
    *) error="bflag";;
  esac
done

  echo $fflag
}
```

I am using the first script as an entry point, because I have other function that do other things, but for some reason the script above does not even show the value of the `$fflag` I tried moving out the getopts loop out of the function to no avail

Comment: Are you  running this script exactly above. It cannot run actually!

Comment: Move the part `if [[ "$1" == "update" ]]; then
    updater 
fi` below the function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 issues:

1. Define a function first at the start and then call it in your script
2. You need to pass command line to your function using `"$@"`
3. Before passing command line arguments call `shift` to remove first argument

You can use this script:

```
updater() {
    verbose='false'
    fflag=''
    error=''

    while getopts 'f:v' flag; do
      case "$flag" in
        f) fflag="${OPTARG}";;
        v) verbose='false';;
        *) error="bflag";;
      esac
    done

    declare -p fflag
}

if [[ $1 == "update" ]]; then
    shift
    updater "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Inian

Comment: Thanks. Just one last question, is there a way to not show error, if an flag is not set? I get something like `option requires an argument -- ..` if just call the script

Comment: Are you trying to call it as: `bash foo.sh update -f` ? Options `f` has `:` after it so it does need an argument