# Bash: Extract remaining unflagged arguments (when using getopts)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using the `getopts` command to process the flags in my bash script, using the structure found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128172/2230446

```
#!/bin/bash
t_flag='30'

print_usage() {
  printf "Usage: ..."
}

while getopts 't:' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    t) t_flag="${OPTARG}" ;;
    *) print_usage
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

echo "${t_flag}"
```

I run the script with the following command:

`./test.sh -t dog cat fish`

My goal is to extract `cat fish` to a variable so I can use it in the rest of the script, similar to how the `t_flag` was extracted to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discard `-t dog` after parsing it, e.g:

```
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Then only `cat` and `fish` will be left as positional parameters. To extract them to a variable:

```
var=$*
```