# I am having trouble understanding what ${@} means in KSH

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

Not a long question, what does this mean?

```
LogMsg "File:${@}"
```

LogMsg() is a method that logs a message with a timestamp.

But what the heck does

```
${@}
```

mean?  I should also mention the script also has $1 and $2 as well. Google produces no results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally:

```
f() { printf '%s\n' "File: $@"; }
f "First Argument" "Second Argument" "Third Argument"
```

will expand to and run the command:

```
printf '%s\n' "File: First Argument" "Second Argument" "Third Argument"
```

That is to say: It expands your argument list (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc) while maintaining separation between subsequent arguments (not throwing away any information provided by the user by way of quoting).

---

This is different from:

```
printf '%s\n' File: $@
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' File: $*
```

which are both the same as:

```
printf '%s\n' "File:" "First" "Argument" "Second" "Argument" "Third" "Argument"
```

...these both string-split and glob-expand the argument list, so if the user had passed, say, `"*"` (inside quotes intended to make it literal), the unquoted use here would replace that character with the results of expanding it as a glob, ie. the list of files in the current directory. Also, string-splitting has other side effects such as changing newlines or tabs to spaces.

---

It is also different from:

```
printf '%s\n' "File: $*"
```

which is the same as:

```
printf '%s\n' "File: First Argument Second Argument Third Argument"
```

...which, as you can see above, combines all arguments by putting the first character in `IFS` (which is by default a space) between them.

Answer (score 2):

in `KSH` there is two positional paremeters `*` and `@`

`"$*"` is a single string that consists of all of the positional parameters, separated by the first character in the variable IFS (internal field separator), which is a space, TAB, and newline by default.

On the other hand, `"$@"` is equal to `"$1" "$2" … "$N "`, where `N` is the number of positional parameters.

For more detailed information and example : http://oreilly.com/catalog/korn2/chapter/ch04.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of the arguments of the command line.
If you launch a script via a command like `cmd a b c d`, there is 5 arguments, `$0` will be the command `cmd`, `$1`the first argument `a`, `$2` the second `b`, etc. `${@}` will be all the arguments except the command.

Comment: Like the entire line of what was passed in to the script?

Comment: @R4F6, yes -- split out as separate arguments (if quoted as `"$@"`), vs `$*` which combines them together. Using `$@` without quotes is just the same as `$*`, and thus typically a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The one piece that was not explained by the other posts is the use of `{`.  `$@` is the same as `${@}` but allows you to add letters, etc if needed and those letters will not have a space added in.  e.g. you could say `${foo}dog` and if $foo was set to `little` the result would be `littledog` with no spaces.  In the case of `${@}dogdog` and `$@` is set to `a b c d` the result is "a" "b" "c" "ddogdog".