# Pass arguments to python from bash script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have been working on a script mixture of `bash` and `python` script. The bash script can receive unknown count input arguments. For example :

```
tinify.sh  test1.jpg test2.jpg test3.jpg .....
```

After the bash receives all, it pass these arguments to `tinify.py`. Now I have come out two ways to do that.

- Loop in `bash` and call `python tinify.py testx.jpg`

  In another word, `python tinify test1.jpg` then `python tinify test2.jpg`, finaly `python tinify test3.jpg`
- Pass all arguments to `tinify.py` then loop in `python`

But there is a problem, I want to filter same parameter for example if user input `tinify.sh  test1.jpg test1.jpg test1.jpg` , I only want `tinify.sh test1.jpg`.So I think it's easier to do in second way because python may be convenient.

**How can I do to pass all arguments to python script?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course, loop in python at once. No need to call the same python script for each argument

Comment: So how can I pass all parameters to python script?@RomanPerekhrest

Comment: via delimiter-separated string or json string

Comment: pass arguments to python within bash: pythonscript.sh $@, then use "import sys
print sys.argv[0]" for first arguments in python and so on. You can loop within python.

Comment: @Ardit Can you explain with an example?

Comment: @Ardit, needs to be `"$@"`, not bare `$@`, or you're splitting on spaces, expanding literal globs in names, and otherwise not passing the input exactly as it was received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `$@` in `tinify.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
tinify.py "$@"
```

It will be far easier to eliminate duplicates inside the Python script that to filter them out from the shell. (Of course, this raises the question whether you need a shell script at all.)

Comment: I agree that elimination of duplicates are way better accomplished in Python. I agree that the use of the bash script here is really superficial. However, this is already pointed out in previous comments. The OP asks how to filter the arguments in bash. Not in Python.

Comment: I think sometimes it's more convenient to use `./tinify.sh test1.jpg test2.jpg` than `python tinify.py test1.jpg test2.jpg` although they both works well for me. Is there any other convenient way to invoke them ?

Comment: If you add `#!/usr/bin/python` (or whatever is appropriate) to the Python script and make it executable, you can simply run `./tinify.py test1.jpg test2.jpg`.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Chepner's answer above:

```
#!/bin/bash
tinify.py "$@"
```

within python script, tinify.py:

```
from sys import argv
inputArgs = sys.argv[1:]
def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))
arguments=remove_duplicates(inputArgs)
```

The list `arguments` will contain the arguments passed to python script (duplicated removed as `set` can't contain duplicated values in python).

Comment: `remove_duplicates(sys.argv[1:])`

Answer (score 1):

A python program can accept any number of command line arguments, using `sys.argv` — just remember that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script
and actual arguments are contained in `sys.argv[1:]`

```
$ cat test_args.py
from sys import argv

prog_name = argv[0]
print('Program name:', prog_name)

for arg in argv[1:]:
    print(arg)
$ python test_args.py a b 'c d'
Program name: test_args.py
a
b
c d
$
```

note that an argument containing spaces must be quoted according to the shell syntax.

Comment: Do you understand my question ? I do not know how to pass all arguments from bash script to python.

Comment: Do you understand my answer?  You can write the Python part so that the shell can pass any number of arguments, e.g.: `python tinify.py $@` if you don't want to touch the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `tinify.py` should start with the following (if you have two arguments):

```
import sys

arg1, arg2 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
```

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself. You can of course loop over `sys.argv`. Personally, i like to pass all the arguments as json objects, so afterwards I do `json.loads()`

Comment: So how can I pass to python script ?

Comment: Regarding the problem with unique args ```tinify.sh test1.jpg test1.jpg test1.jpg``` should become ```tinify.sh test1.jpg```, you could use a set. For example ```set([sys.argv[i] for i in range(your_number_of_args)])```

Comment: Thanks a lot @con--

Comment: No problem. You pass the args to the python script the same way as the bash script. If you call ```tinify.py test1.jpg``` sys.argv[1] will be "test1.jpg". If you want a variable number of args you can count the args using ```len(sys.argv)``` Within the bash script I think you can pass all args using "$@". Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine) answer