# Handling named arguments in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the script. When I ran this with command

```
./scriptname --deploy --uglify"
```

I'm getting result for `echo "$deploy"` as `true`. But it should be `uglify` right since `deploy=$2`

```
#!/bin/bash

deploy=true
uglify=true

while (( $# > 1 )); do 
    case $1 in
    --deploy) deploy="$2" echo "$deploy";;
    --uglify) uglify="$2";;
    *) break;
    esac; shift 2
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you mean something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

deploy=false
uglify=false

while (( $# >= 1 )); do 
    case $1 in
    --deploy) deploy=true;;
    --uglify) uglify=true;;
    *) break;
    esac;
    shift
done

echo "deploy: $deploy"
echo "uglify: $uglify"
```

**examples**

```
$ ./scriptname
deploy: false
uglify: false


$ ./scriptname --deploy
deploy: true
uglify: false


$ ./scriptname --uglily
deploy: false
uglify: true

$ ./scriptname --depoly --uglily
deploy: true
uglify: true
```

Answer (score 1):

While dealing with this I came up with the following. We encapsulate all the procedure inside a function that takes all the arguments given to the script. Then,  it iterates over all the arguments and whenever it find one that starts with double hyphen `--arg1` it assigns the following argument `arg2` to a global variable with the name of the first argument `arg1="arg2"`. Next, it shifts the arguments' positions until it finish with all arguments.

```sh
#------ arguments_test.sh ------
#!/bin/bash
pararser() {
    # Define default values
    name=${name:-"name_def"}
    lastName=${lastName:-"lastName_def"}

    # Assign the values given by the user
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        if [[ $1 == *"--"* ]]; then
            param="${1/--/}"
            declare -g $param="$2"
        fi
        shift
    done

}


pararser $@

echo "My name is " $name $lastName
```

In this way we can define default values if they are not passed.

```
$ arguments_test.sh
> My name is name_def lastName_def
```

```
$ arguments_test.sh --name Foo --lastName Bar
> My name is Foo Bar
```

## Some references

- The main procedure was found [here](https://brianchildress.co/named-parameters-in-bash/).
- More about passing all the arguments to a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3816747/5969548).
- More info regarding default values [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122848/404005).
- More info about `declare` do `$ bash -c "help declare"`.
- More info about `shift` do `$ bash -c "help shift"`.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in the command are all expanded before anything is executed, so the old value of `$deploy` is used in the expansion. So it's executing

```
deploy="--uglify" echo "true"
```

Change that line to:

```
    --deploy) deploy="$2"; echo "$deploy";;
```

If you don't want to change the value of `deploy` in the script process, you can run `echo` in a subprocess:

```
    --deploy) deploy="$2" bash -c 'echo "$deploy"';;
```