# How to pass options to a docker ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker

Consider the command:

```
ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

Options come first, and then comes the file. However, somehow, I have no idea why, `ls` does not insists on this order. Therefore `ls -la /home` and `ls /home -la` produce identical output.

We can use this quirk to send **options** to a `ls` that knows its `[FILE]` argument.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "/home"]
```

Then passing arguments is the same as passing options:

```
$ docker build -t test .
$ docker run test
$ docker run test -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 May 12 16:58 ..
```

However some programs insist on the order of options and arguments. For instance a `.jar` with a Spring server application:

This works as intended:

```
 java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=ci backend.jar
```

This does not:

```
 java -jar backend.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=ci
```

The `[COMMAND]` and `[ARG...]` in `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]` seem to be **appended** to the entrypoint and **not inserted**.

Is there any way to pass options instead of arguments to a docker `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: Also see [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation, and discussion of the [container-as-command pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).  (Also the [recommendation for `CMD` to be a complete command](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#cmd) in the same document.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you use as `CMD`, may it be from the Dockerfile or when running the image, is passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as arguments.

You can create a more sophisticated entrypoint, preferable via script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec java -jar $@ backend.jar
```

I am using `$@` which are all the args passed to the script, effectively the `CMD`.

Additionally, I am using `exec` to make the final `java` command run with process ID (pid) 1, so that it receives signals properly. For example `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for this.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=ci", "backend.jar"]
```

This also allows you to change the parameters at runtime. E.g.

```
docker run <image> -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=debug backend.jar
```

Comment: The `ENTRYPOINT` _must_ be in JSON-array form `ENTRYPOINT ["java"]` for this to work.  I wouldn't recommend just using an interpreter as the `ENTRYPOINT` here, but if you make the whole thing `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "backend.jar"]` then any (`CMD`) arguments will be visible to the `main()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a java guy so I'm not familiar with how arguments should go, but it seems in the original post that the profile needs to be in the middle. I fixed the `ENTRYPOINT`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the `java -jar backend.jar` part, you can add a tiny shell script that takes the arguments you put at the end and passes them before. [See the selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine) for details on how to do that